# Powershell Invalid Index Error When Using Excel Cells?

Tags: excel, powershell

I am currently working on a script where I use several arrays to lookup inventory lists in Excel. After running a few tests I can get my script to read the contents of each cell (thanks to some research from this site!) but I can't use the contents of the cell in a variable. I receive an "Invalid Index" error when I try to switch to a worksheet using contents from one of the cells being read. I've also added an example of how the data is arranged.

```
#Test array
$array = "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Tiger"

#Location of the Excel file to edit
$FileLoc = "Q:\Cutsheet.xlsx"

#Create Excel Com Object, and display it
$excel = new-object -com Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $true

#Open Workbook
$workbooks = $excel.workbooks.Open($FileLoc)
$worksheets = $workbooks.Worksheets
$worksheet = $worksheets.item("DATA")

#opens inventory workbook
$source = $excel.workbooks.Open("Q:\inventory.xlsx")
$sourceSheets = $source.Worksheets

<# 
#This loop will search for match element of the array with a corresponding cell on an excel spreadsheet.
#That cell is grouped with several names of inventory worksheet names. The script will copy each inventory
#and append it to the existing cutsheet.
#>

foreach($element in $array) {
for ($i = 9; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
if ($worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Text -eq $element) {
$j = 2
while ($worksheet.Cells.Item($i, $j).Text -ne "") {
Write-Host $worksheet.Cells.Item($i, $j).Value2
$name = $worksheet.Cells.Item($i, $j).Value2
$sourceSheet = $sourceSheets.Item($name)
$sourceSheet.Copy([system.type]::missing, $worksheets)
$j++
}
}
}
}
```

[Example spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0QtO.png)

Comment: Looks like you need `$sourceSheet.Copy([system.type]::missing, $worksheet)`, since the parameter for that is a worksheet object to paste the copied worksheet after, and you are currently referencing a collection of worksheets, not a specific worksheet.

Comment: Ah, you're right about that! I didn't even start to address that error, but the line above that is where I'm getting the indexing error.

Comment: Have you verified that `$name` contains a valid value, and that there is indeed a worksheet that matches it exactly? For example, I see cell E9 that contains ' Flee Collar' and cell E10 that contains 'Flee Collar'. E9 has a preceding space before the words, so are there two similar tabs, that that has a leading space and one that doesn't? Or was that simply a typo?

Comment: I can echo the values of each cell in order using the below line:

    Write-Host $worksheet.Cells.Item($i, $j).Value2

Would that verify that the cells contain valid values?

Comment: Try running `$($sourceSheets).Name` and see if the values in your cells appear in that list. The error you're getting is that it can't find the worksheet that you have indicated, so Excel can't find a sheet with a name that corresponds with the value of the cell you're referencing.